# Create a PySpark function that determines if two or more selected columns in a dataframe have null values

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I want to create a PySpark function that determines if values in two or more columns of a PySpark dataframe are null. A new column should be made to show TRUE or FALSE if values in both columns have been populated. The function should stop processing if it encounters null values in both columns. The output should look like this:

| firstname | lastnam | Values Not in Table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Wilson | false |
| George | Johnson | false |
| null | Kasey | true |

^The above would stop processing once it hurts a null or empty value in the table. Thanks in advance!

The code below shows if a value in ONE column of a dataframe is null. I want a new function that does this with 2 or more columns:

```
def isValueNull(df, column_name, file_name):
    new_df = df.select(df[column_name]).withColumn('Value not in ' + file_name,
    F.when((df[column_name] =='') | (df[column_name] == 'Null') | (df[column_name] == 'null') | (df[column_name] == 'NULL'), True).otherwise(False))
    
    return new_df
```

Comment: So, what did you try so far? Please share your code with us.

Comment: I posted my code so far above. It only deals with one column though. I want it to to deal with two columns.

Comment: Thank you, my comment went just few seconds before your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, scenarios like this use the `dropna()` function provided by PySpark. For example, consider the dataframe created using:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = sc.parallelize([
        Row(firstname='Bob', lastname='Wilson'),
        Row(firstname='George', lastname='Johnson'),
        Row(firstname=None, lastname='Kasey'),
        Row(firstname='John', lastname=None),
        Row(firstname='John', lastname='Kasey')]).toDF()
df.show()
```

This would look like this:

```
+---------+--------+
|firstname|lastname|
+---------+--------+
|      Bob|  Wilson|
|   George| Johnson|
|     null|   Kasey|
|     John|    null|
|     John|   Kasey|
+---------+--------+
```

Using `dropna()` on `firstname` and `lastname` like this:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['firstname', 'lastname'])
df.show()
```

would produce the output:

```
+---------+--------+
|firstname|lastname|
+---------+--------+
|      Bob|  Wilson|
|   George| Johnson|
|     John|   Kasey|
+---------+--------+
```

But in your case, a new column is required as an indicator. I do not think there exists a function that accepts a list of columns and produces the output you desire. That being said, what you are looking for can be achieved using multiple methods. One such method is as follows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
columns_list = ['firstname', 'lastname']
new_df = df.withColumn("Values Not in Table", F.lit(False))
for column_name in columns_list:
    new_df = new_df.withColumn('Values Not in Table', F.when(~new_df['Values Not in Table'] & new_df[column_name].isNull(), True).otherwise(new_df['Values Not in Table']))
new_df.show()
```

This would produce the output:

```
+---------+--------+-------------------+
|firstname|lastname|Values Not in Table|
+---------+--------+-------------------+
|      Bob|  Wilson|              false|
|   George| Johnson|              false|
|     null|   Kasey|               true|
|     John|    null|               true|
|     John|   Kasey|              false|
+---------+--------+-------------------+
```

By updating the variable `columns_list` you can achieve the desired functionality easily.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the `condition expression` for each column inside a loop and then use this expression inside `withColumn`.

### Working Example

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from typing import List
data = [("Bob", "Wilson", ),
        ("George", "Johnson", ), 
        ("null", "Kasey", ),
        ("NULL", "Kasey", ),
        ("Null", "Kasey", ),
        ("", "Kasey", ),
        (None, "Kasey", ),
        ("Bob", None, ),
        ("Bob", "Null", ),
        ("Bob", "", ),
        ("Bob", "null", ),
       ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("firstname", "lastname", ))

def isValueNull(df: DataFrame, column_names: List[str], file_name: str) -> DataFrame:
    null_condition = F
    for col in column_names:
        null_condition = null_condition.when((df[col] =='') | (F.lower(df[col]) == 'null') | (df[col].isNull()), True)
    new_df = df.withColumn('Value not in ' + file_name, null_condition.otherwise(False))
    
    return new_df

isValueNull(df, ["firstname", "lastname"], "Table").show()
```

#### Output

```
---------+--------+------------------+
|firstname|lastname|Value not in Table|
+---------+--------+------------------+
|      Bob|  Wilson|             false|
|   George| Johnson|             false|
|     null|   Kasey|              true|
|     NULL|   Kasey|              true|
|     Null|   Kasey|              true|
|         |   Kasey|              true|
|     null|   Kasey|              true|
|      Bob|    null|              true|
|      Bob|    Null|              true|
|      Bob|        |              true|
|      Bob|    null|              true|
+---------+--------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will only work if there are only two columns:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
data = [("Bob", "Wilson", ),
    ("George", "Johnson", ), 
    ("null", "Kasey", ),
    ("NULL", "Kasey", ),
    ("Null", "Kasey", ),
    ("", "Kasey", ),
    (None, "Kasey", ),
    ("Bob", None, ),
    ("Bob", "Null", ),
    ("Bob", "", ),
    ("Bob", "null", ),
   ]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("firstname", "lastname" ))

col_list = df.columns

def  isValueNull(df, column_name, file_name):
  lst = []

  for col in column_name:
    val = F.when((df[col] == '')| (F.lower(df[col]) == 'null') | (df[col].isNull()), True)
    df = df.withColumn('new_col_' + col,val.otherwise(False))

  for i in range(len(column_name)):
     if i != len(column_name)-1:
         nw_val = F.when((df['new_col_' + column_name[i]] == False)& (df['new_col_' + column_name[i+1]] == False), False).otherwise(True)
         df = df.withColumn('Value not in ' + file_name, nw_val).drop('new_col_' + column_name[i],'new_col_' + column_name[i+1])
else:
  break
return df
display(isValueNull(df,col_list,'TABLE_NAME'))
```

#### Output

[image]